# NULL input from textfield won't NSLog?

Tags: iphone, ios4

I'm trying to debug my iPhone app (a basic counter) and I have a "goto" function to go to a specific number. When testing my app, I noticed that when set the goto without putting anything into the `NSTextField`, it doesn't return anything. Not a `NULL`, `nil`, or anything. `NSLog`ging the input string doesn't even show up in console. No blank message, no `NULL` message, nothing. If you want to see my code, here it is:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
 switch(buttonIndex) {
     case 0:
        break;
     case 1:
        NSLog(@"Method called");
        NSLog(@"%@", [[alertView textField] text]);
     if ([[alertView textField] text] != NULL) {
        count = [[[alertView textField] text] intValue];
        [label setText:[[alertView textField] text]];
     } else { 
        break;
     }
  }
}
```

"Method called" always shows up, but the next line doesn't come up at all on a case with no input.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't show up because I suspect that it has nothing to show!

If you really want to show it no matter what try:

```
NSLog(@"Alertview textfield = %@", [[alertView textField] text]);
```

This way it'll show the first part of the string and then if its got any text to display it'll append that as well

I've just done a very small test and using

```
NSString* text = @"";
NSLog(@"%@",text);
```

and nothing is shown in the console

## ::edit::

If your trying to get the if statement to work you could try using something like

```
if(![[[alertView textField] text] isEqual:@""])
```

What it seems is happening is that the `[[alertView textField] text]` is returning an NSString of `@""` and not `NULL` or `nil`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it still logs as `Alertview textfield = `

Comment: YES! Thank you... I actually smiled when it worked. Thanks again!!!! I totally forgot about `isEqualToString`... d'oh!